# Meaning to Sony Vaio laptop series number

Tags: laptop

For example, VAIO VPC EB64FX BJ.

Is there any site explains the meaning of these series number, and maybe has a list to compare between similar models. For now, I have to crawl a lot sites to figure out VPC = VAIO PC, [EB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_VAIO_E_series#EB_Series) is a series for certain setup like Intel chip, LED back light. BJ means the case is in black. However, I still can't find out the meaning to 64 and FX. Can the community advise? Thanks.

Comment: One would think the manufacturer's web site provided information like this (especially useful product comparison). But I'd be not surprised if Sony's didn't.

Comment: Edited the post since these identifiers are specific to manufacturers.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone knows VAIO is video Audio Integrated Operation.

My vaio is VPC EB36FG/B

- VPC as u have already said, ofcourse stands for Vaio PC.
- E stands for E Series laptops,which normally is a consumer grade version of Vaio with attractive colors,Graphics support etc.
- B stands for a subset of the E series ,for grouping laptops with particular features.(For eg:- EA laptops were 14" ,EB were 15.5")
- The numbers '36' represent a model in the EB series. (For eg:- There was EB26FG before my laptop came to market, now my model is not available , but EB46FG is available. ) As the number changes they make some minor changes also, basically keeping the overall look same.
- In old VAIO models the last two letters were a hint to the operating system it carries (Eg:- V505EX - Came with Windows XP home and V505EXP -Came with windows XP professional) .
- And the letter after the / represents the colour. B= Black ,W= White etc.

So i guess FX basically stands for a XP home editon laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The last letter indicates a specific country (probably where your vaio has been made):

- X is US
- E is UK
- J is Japan
- G is India

...
I figured this out by chance when I had to find drivers for my VPCSE2AJ, and found a (very) closed match from US: VPCSE27FX